# Javascript image onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a javasript code to execute on image click. I wrote the code as follow but it doesn't work, can anyone help me to make this work

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/grid_12.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/slider.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Sketch:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/tms-0.4.1.js"></script>
        <script>

    function click(){
    if(a.document.getElementById=="right")
    {
    document.getElementById('aswE').src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/nature/256/White-Flower-icon.png' ;
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById('aswE').src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flowers-stroke-1/100/flowers_flower_bloom-42-256.png' ;
    }
    $('img.answr').hide();
    return false;
     }

     </script>
     <body>
      <div class="main">
     <div class="container_12"> 
        <table border="0"><tr>
      <td>
     
    <img src="http://www.bigmomentfilms.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Daisy-flowers.jpg" alt="Elep_ant" border="5" /></td><td><img src="" alt="" name="aswE" width="103" height="99" id="aswE" />
    </br>
    <a href="#" onclick="click()">    
    <img class="answr" src=""http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/orange_flower_115.jpg" id="wrong" /></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="click()">    
    <img class="answr" src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/quilted-floral-icons-natural-wonders/053719-quilted-floral-icon-natural-wonders-flower2.png" id="right" width="103" height="99" /></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="click()">    
    <img src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/magic-marker-icons-natural-wonders/115597-magic-marker-icon-natural-wonders-flower17.png" id="wrong" width="103" height="99"/></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="click()">    
    <img src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/blue-chrome-rain-icons-natural-wonders/050122-blue-chrome-rain-icon-natural-wonders-flower17.png" id="wrong" width="103" height="99" /></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="click()">    
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/orange_flower_115.jpg" id="wrong" width="103" height="99"/></a></td></tr></table>



     </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </section>    
       </div>      
    </body>
    </html>
```

as i want this javascript to load another image regarding the clicked image and when user click on an image all the four images must be hide until the page is reloaded again

Comment: **ids** should be unique

Comment: what you want to  do by this
`if(a.document.getElementById=="right")`
this line do nothing

Comment: So Many Mistakes, Please do it in jsfiddle and add

Comment: Agree with @Dinesh Kanivu, and there's not need to put <img> in <a> since what you need it to change the img src after click. Just put your onclick event in the <img> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <img id="aswE" src="http://www.bigmomentfilms.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Daisy-flowers.jpg" alt="Elep_ant" border="5" />
    </br>
    <img class="answr" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/orange_flower_115.jpg" width="103" height="99" />
    <img class="answr" id="correct" src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/quilted-floral-icons-natural-wonders/053719-quilted-floral-icon-natural-wonders-flower2.png" width="103" height="99" />   
    <img class="answr" src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/magic-marker-icons-natural-wonders/115597-magic-marker-icon-natural-wonders-flower17.png" width="103" height="99"/>  
    <img class="answr" src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/blue-chrome-rain-icons-natural-wonders/050122-blue-chrome-rain-icon-natural-wonders-flower17.png" width="103" height="99" />

</body>

<script>
    $('.answr').click(function(){
        if ( $(this).attr('id') === 'correct' ) {
            $('#aswE').attr('src', 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/nature/256/White-Flower-icon.png');
        } else {
            $('#aswE').attr('src', 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flowers-stroke-1/100/flowers_flower_bloom-42-256.png');
        }

        $('.answr').hide();
    });
</script>

</html>
```

**Note**: This version of the script has to come after the body has been loaded, because it will look for anything with class "answr" and bind a click function to it.  If it's loaded before the body, it will find nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Jquery, Don't use the document.getElementById() method. Use the selector engine inside Jquery, It has great cross browser support.

HTML

```
<img src="image1.jpg" id="img1"> // make sure ID's are unique
<img src="image2.jpg" id="img2" style="display:none;">
```

Jquery

```
$('#img1').click(function(){
    $('#img2').show();
});
```

[Click here to see JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52rrm3wu/)

Answer (score 1):

Ok your issue is because you can't rename your function `click()`. this conflict with javascript formating. I have rename your function to `clicks()` and i pass the element object in parameter with `this`

> clicks(this)

And now i check if the children element have the good id.

Now it's work. Please try

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/grid_12.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/slider.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Sketch:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/tms-0.4.1.js"></script>
        <script>

    function clicks(s){

    if(s.children[0]=="right")
    {
    document.getElementById('aswE').src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/nature/256/White-Flower-icon.png' ;
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById('aswE').src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flowers-stroke-1/100/flowers_flower_bloom-42-256.png' ;
      
    }

    $("img.answr").hide();
    return false;
     }

     </script>
     <body>
      <div class="main">
     <div class="container_12"> 
        <table border="0"><tr>
      <td>
     
    <img src="http://www.bigmomentfilms.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Daisy-flowers.jpg" alt="Elep_ant" border="5" /></td><td><img src="" alt="" name="aswE" width="103" height="99" id="aswE" />

    <a href="#" onclick="clicks(this)">    
    <img class="answr" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/orange_flower_115.jpg" id="wrong" /></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="clicks(this)">    
    <img class="answr" src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/quilted-floral-icons-natural-wonders/053719-quilted-floral-icon-natural-wonders-flower2.png" id="right" width="103" height="99" /></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="clicks(this)">    
    <img src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/magic-marker-icons-natural-wonders/115597-magic-marker-icon-natural-wonders-flower17.png" id="wrong" width="103" height="99"/></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="clicks(this)">    
    <img src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/blue-chrome-rain-icons-natural-wonders/050122-blue-chrome-rain-icon-natural-wonders-flower17.png" id="wrong" width="103" height="99" /></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="clicks(this)">    
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/orange_flower_115.jpg" id="wrong" width="103" height="99"/></a>
          </td>
       </tr>
       </table>



     </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </section>    
       </div>      
    </body>
    </html>
```

You can find more details for reserved words here : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to use class for that img and getElementsByClassName because there is multiple id with same name, and there are not any id in a tag, you have palce id in img tag,
Change some code in javascript and as well as in HTML.